# Why is the search domain in /etc/resolv.conf used for ALL queries?

Tags: linux, dns

According to many guides I've found, the search domain in /etc/resolv.conf should be used for **dotless** queries only. However, man resolv.conf says this about the *ndots* option:

> sets  a  threshold for the number of dots which must appear in a name
>   given to res_query(3) (see resolver(3)) before an initial absolute
>   query will be made.  The default for  n  is  1,  meaning that  if 
>   there  are any dots in a name, the name will be tried first as an
>   absolute name before any search list elements are appended to it.  The
>   value for this option is  silently  capped  to 15.

This contradicts the claims about search domains being used only for dotless queries, and also seems to be true. I first noticed it by accident using tcpdump. When resolving for example reallynonexistentdomain.com, and my resolv.conf contains 'search test.com', the result is two queries: reallynonexistentdomain.com and reallynonexistentdomain.com.test.com. Both queries get the NXDOMAIN answer, and resolving seems to work as it should, but is there any way to prevent the latter query? It is obviously bogus and (not 100% sure about this) a potential security risk.

What practical reasons are there anyway for appending the search domain to a fully qualified domain name (or more specifically, a name with at least *ndots* dots)? I can't think of any. Wouldn't it be better if the resolver just didn't try use the search domain at all when the original query is answered with NXDOMAIN, provided that it had at least *ndots* dots?

I'm using Debian wheezy. Could the behavior be different on other distributions, or other UNIX-like systems?

Answer (score 2):

The practical reason for this behaviour is very simple: if your organization uses `example.com` domain, and its sales department uses `sales.example.com` domain, then you should be able to access FQDN `fileserver.sales.example.com` as simply `fileserver.sales`. This is really handy if you have many internal hosts/sites, and saves quite a lot of typing.

Note that *ndots* option is only deals with the *initial* query, e.g. should be initial query be sent as-is, or with the local domain appended. If the first verbatim query failed, resolver will always append the local domain and try again. This has nothing to do with the number of dots.

Many auto-discovery protocols and services depend on this DNS behaviour.  There is no security risk **as long as the local domain is under your control**. E.g. if somebody types `gogle.com` and your local domain is **not** under your control, it is trivial to set up a rogue server at gogle.com.example.com to intercept these typos.